# How do I change my existing R codes from the output of a random sample to a list of all possible outcomes?

Tags: r, random, combinations

I have the following `R` codes running in `RStudio`:

```
foo <- list(
  c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),  
  c(11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19),  
  c(21, 25, 28, 29),  
  c(31, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40) 
)

names(foo) <- c(2, 1, 2, 1)

is.odd <- function(x) x %% 2 != 0

countOdds <- function(dt) {
  sum(sapply(dt, is.odd))
  }


while(TRUE) {
  list2 <- unlist(sapply(seq_along(foo), function(x) 
    sample(foo[[x]], names(foo[x]))))
  if(countOdds(list2) == 2)
    break
}

sort(list2)
```

What the actual codes do:

The output is a random output (1 single outcome) from all possible outcomes.

```
Example: 2  6 16 25 28 37
```

In this output, we have 2 `ODD` numbers and 4 `EVEN` numbers as specified in the last part of the codes.

What I want to achieve:

I need to modify the codes so that it gives me ALL the possible outcomes from what has been specified instead of a single random output.
Ideally, I would like to write this new output into a `CSV` file.

Say, something like:

```
write.csv(result1, file="result1.csv")
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was interesting problem to solve and maybe mine is not the most efficient approach but one way to solve this is

```
#First get all possible combinations based on the names
#For example, from list 1 we want to select 2 element, from list 2 only 1 and so on
#simplify is kept FALSE for the same purpose so that we get a list as outcome
#and those elements are treated as a group and not individual elements
all_combn <- sapply(seq_along(foo) ,function(x) combn(foo[[x]], 
                     as.numeric(names(foo[x])), simplify = FALSE))

#Now create a dataframe where each row is one possible outcome
expanded <- expand.grid(all_combn)

#however, the problem is where there are more than 1 items to select it has 
#columns as list, so we need to expand those list elements to separate columns
all_values <- t(apply(expanded, 1, unlist))

#Now select rows where our condition is satisfied
final <- all_values[apply(all_values, 1, countOdds) == 2, ]
final

#       Var11 Var12 Var2 Var31 Var32 Var4
#  [1,]     2     6   16    21    28   31
#  [2,]     2     8   16    21    28   31
#  [3,]     6     8   16    21    28   31
#  [4,]     2     6   16    25    28   31
#  [5,]     2     8   16    25    28   31
#  [6,]     6     8   16    25    28   31
#  [7,]     2     6   16    28    29   31
#  [8,]     2     8   16    28    29   31
#  [9,]     6     8   16    28    29   31
# [10,]     2     6   16    21    28   33
#.....
```

Now you can write this `final` to csv using `write.csv` or any other method.

Comment: Thanks for giving this a try. If I understand well, your set of codes plugs in and replaces all codes after "while(TRUE)..." in my existing codes?

Comment: @user3115933 yes, I have taken `foo`, `is.odd` and `countOdds` function from you. This replaces everything after and including `while(TRUE)` .